# The User.Identity is lost under a load balance scenario for my ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I use `Windows Authentication` with a load balanced website. The load balance is based on two IIS web servers. There is a feature in my site which allow users to relogon like *Sharepoint sign-in as different user*.

But I notice that while I relogon, the `User.Identity` in one site is changed but the other site still keep the prior account.

I suspect there are something in the cookie should be clear.

Has anyone faced this problem while playing with loading balance? Or do you know some related article which might help?

I don't know how to fix the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

**by the way
I use this method to archieve the relogon it works on single server. http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=825.**


Hello guys,

I still work on this feature.
I print the User.Identity.Name in my home page. when I change the account, the User.Identity.Name output is changed correctly. but when I refresh the home page, sometimes the prior account will be displayed on the home page.

Comment: I missed the part of your question where you specified Windows authentication. They are very different. Sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: Is the user a domain account, where each web server is on the domain, or is the user account or local to each web server?

Comment: Hi David, yes I have test accounts for testing this feature. both of them are domain account. and our web servers are also on the domain.

Comment: seems, no solution, no need to attempt to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your comments correctly, your setup involves two web servers, each with a local user with the same name (and presumably the same password), and you're attempting to use Windows authentication in the web farm scenario.

In your situation, each computer has it's own account with a name - assume your username is "AuthorizedUser".  Bear in mind that if AuthorizedUser is a local account on both machines, then these are two *completely different* user accounts.  Each computer checks it's own user account information to verify the identity of the person, and in a non-Domain situation, Computer A has no reason to trust a user that was authenticated on Computer B.

If it *were* possible that computer A trusted computer B without a domain scenario - just two random computers that happen to have a user with the same name, imagine how easy it would be to hack into anyone's web server that's using Windows Authentication.  All you'd have to do is guess a valid username, rather than a valid username/password combination.  It's easy to see why this is a bad idea.

For Windows Authentication to work in a web farm scenario, you need to be using a Domain user (A Windows NT Domain) and that Domain User needs to have the same permissions set up on two servers.  This way, there is only one AuthorizedUser, and both web servers can verify the identity against the domain.  Both web servers will automatically trust that the Domain Controller has authorized the user properly and will trust the domain.

Comment: Hi David, thanks very much. I am not familiar with web farm. our network engineer config the DNS, NLB and other related work. what i need to do is create a website in each server on the port 80. and deploy the same application under the websites.
but what I can confirm is that our account are all domain account, not local account. 
I will ask our network engineer tomrrow, maybe I can get something related the web farm.
I will post here, if I get progress.